# Как сделать чтобы можно было изменять с админики WP парметры в WP_Query{}?

Tags: php, wordpress

Всем доброго дня!
На сайте реализовал вывод популярных постов по просмотрам

```
<?php

                $populargb = new WP_Query('showposts=3&meta_key=post_views_count&orderby=meta_value_num&cat=2' );
                while ( $populargb->have_posts() ) {
                    $populargb->the_post(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php trim_title_chars(55, '...'); ?></a>
                        <div class="preview_text">
                            <?php echo trim_characters(100, '...'); ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="viewsBox">
                            <span class="icon"></span>
                            <span class="quantity"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
```

Как можно реализовать чтобы с админки изменять параметр WP_Query (showposts="...") , т.е нужно чтобы пользователь мог зайти и с админки мог менять кол-во выводимых популярных постов

Заранее благодарю за Ваши мысли.

П.С: плагины не подходять , нужно сделать именно так

Comment: Где в админке вы хотите добавить эту настройку? Возможные варианты: 1) в настройках темы (Внешний вид => Настроить), 2) на странице редактирования страницы, 3) в виджете, 4) на отдельной странице, которую вы создаете например для настройки вашей темы.

Answer (score 2):

**1 вариант (с использованием плагина):**

Вы можете использовать ACF (Advanced Custom Fields), создать поле для данной страницы и вместо статического значения вывести значение этого поля.

```
    <?php

    $count = get_field('count');
    $populargb = new WP_Query(array(
     'showposts' => $count,
     'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'cat' => 2
    ));
     while ( $populargb->have_posts() ) {

     $populargb->the_post(); ?>

     <li>
      <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php trim_title_chars(55, '...'); ?></a>
       <div class="preview_text">
        <?php echo trim_characters(100, '...'); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="viewsBox">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="quantity"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
       </div>
      </li>
     <?php } ?>
```

**2 вариант (без использования плагина):**

в functions.php регистрируете секцию и поле:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'post_count_settings_api_init' );
function post_count_settings_api_init() {
add_settings_section(
    'post_count_setting_section',
    'Управление постами',
    '',
    'general' // страница
);

add_settings_field(
    'count',
    'Кол-во постов:',
    'post_count_setting_callback_function',
    'general', // страница
    'post_count_setting_section'
);
}

function post_count_setting_callback_function() {
echo '<input name="count" type="number" value="' . get_option( 'count' ) . '" class="small-text" />
<p class="description">Введите кол-во постов</p>';
}
```

Данная секция и поле выведется на странице "Настройки" > "Общие". Логичнее будет вывести на странице "Чтение", в таком случае замените `general` на `reading`
Вызов этого поля в шаблоне производится `get_option('count');`

```
    <?php

    $count = get_option('count');
    $populargb = new WP_Query(array(
     'showposts' => $count,
     'meta_key' => 'post_views_count',
     'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
     'cat' => 2
    ));
     while ( $populargb->have_posts() ) {

     $populargb->the_post(); ?>

     <li>
      <a title="<?php the_title(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="title"><?php trim_title_chars(55, '...'); ?></a>
       <div class="preview_text">
        <?php echo trim_characters(100, '...'); ?>
       </div>
       <div class="viewsBox">
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <span class="quantity"><?php echo getPostViews(get_the_ID()); ?></span>
       </div>
      </li>
     <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Автор просил решение без плагинов. Да и ради одного дополнительного поля не стоит подключать целый плагин.

Comment: да, спасибо, не обратил внимание, дописал альтернативный вариант